# How to bevel a stretched rectangle

Tags: c++, math, opengl, glsl

I am able to bevel  the corner of a rectangle.

[image]

When i strech the rectangle and than try to bevel it then the result does not look smooth , it should look like the rectangle on the right side.

[image]

How do i calculate the points for the trianlgle fan when the rectangle is streched ?

currently this is the way i am calculating the points for the Quarter circle.

```
std::vector<float> bevelData;
bevelData.push_back(0.0); // First set the centre of the rectangle to the data
bevelData.push_back(0.0);
bevelData.push_back(0.0);
bevelData.push_back(0);
bevelData.push_back(0);
bevelData.push_back(1);
bevelData.push_back(0);
bevelData.push_back(0);
for (int i = 0; i <= segments; ++i) {
    float x, y;
    float angle = start_angle +  0.5 * M_PI * i / static_cast<float>(segments);
    x = circX + cos(angle) * rad;  // circX is the centre of the circle as marked in yellow in the first image 
    y = circY + sin(angle) * rad;  // circY is the centre of the circle as marked in yellow in the first image , rad is the radius of the circle
    bevelData.push_back(x);
    bevelData.push_back(y);
    bevelData.push_back(0.0);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    bevelData.push_back(1);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
}
```

After applying soultion this is the result i get.
[image]

```
//Bevel Bottom Right
    float rightWidthBottom = (width / 2) - rightBottomBevel;
    float rightHeightBottom = (height / 2) - rightBottomBevel;
    std::vector<float> bottomRightBevelData = draw_bevel(rightWidthBottom, rightHeightBottom, rightBottomBevel, 1, -1, iSegmentsRightBottom);



std::vector<float> SuperRectangle::draw_bevel(float p_x, float p_y, float rad, int dir_x, int dir_y , int segments)
{
    std::vector<float> bevelData;
    float c_x, c_y;   // the center of the circle
    float start_angle; // the angle where to start the arc
    bevelData.push_back(0.0);
    bevelData.push_back(0.0);
    bevelData.push_back(0.0);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    bevelData.push_back(1);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    bevelData.push_back(0);
    c_x = p_x  * dir_x;
    c_y = p_y  * dir_y;
    if (dir_x == 1 && dir_y == 1)
        start_angle = 0.0;
    else if (dir_x == 1 && dir_y == -1)
        start_angle = -M_PI * 0.5f;
    else if (dir_x == -1 && dir_y == 1)
        start_angle = M_PI * 0.5f;
    else if (dir_x == -1 && dir_y == -1)
        start_angle =  M_PI;
    for (int i = 0; i <= segments; ++i) {
        float x, y;
        float angle = start_angle +  0.5 * M_PI * i / static_cast<float>(segments);
        x = c_x + cos(angle) * rad;
        y = c_y + sin(angle) * rad;
        float fscale = (y / (float)(height / 2.0f));        
        x =  (x + (strech * fscale));
        bevelData.push_back(x);
        bevelData.push_back(y);
        bevelData.push_back(0.0);
        bevelData.push_back(0);
        bevelData.push_back(0);
        bevelData.push_back(1);
        bevelData.push_back(0);
        bevelData.push_back(0);
    }
    return bevelData;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
float xWidth  =  width / 2;
float yHeight  = height / 2;
float TriangleRight[] = {
        // positions               // Normals      // Texture Coord
         0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f ,      0.0f,0.0,1.0,   0.0,0.0,  
         xWidth + strech ,  yHeight - rightTopBevel,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,    
         xWidth - strech , -yHeight + rightBottomBevel,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,   
    };


float TriangleLeft[] = {
        // positions      
         0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f ,      0.0f,0.0,1.0,   0.0,0.0,
         -xWidth + strech  ,  yHeight - leftTopBevel ,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
        -xWidth - strech , -yHeight + leftBottomBevel,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
    };


float TriangleTop[] = {
        // positions      
         0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f ,      0.0f,0.0,1.0,   0.0,0.0,
         xWidth - rightTopBevel + strech ,  yHeight ,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
         -xWidth + leftTopBevel + strech , yHeight,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
    };


float TriangleBottom[] = {
        // positions      
         0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f ,      0.0f,0.0,1.0,   0.0,0.0,
         xWidth - rightBottomBevel - strech ,  -yHeight ,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
         -xWidth + leftBottomBevel - strech , -yHeight,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to do this with vertices? I had the same problem as you, my solution was to just make a rectangle and give each vertex a normal and calculate this in the fragment shader. It will also look better, because it will be calculated per fragment instead of per vertex.

Comment: @Rhu Mage yes i would need to do this with vertices as i would extrude this geometry also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a rectangle with a width `w` and a height `h`

```non
 (-w/2, h/2)                  (w/2, h/2)
            +----------------+
            |                |
            |                |
            |                |
            |                |
            +----------------+
(-w/2, -h/2)                  (w/2, -h/2)
```

The points for the rounded corner of the rectangle are calculated by:

```cpp
x = circX + cos(angle) * rad;
y = circY + sin(angle) * rad;
```

Then the rectangle is displaced by `d`. At the top `d` is add to the *x* component of the corner points and at the bottom `d` is subtracted from the *x* component of the corner points:

```non
 (-w/2 + d, h/2)                  (w/2 + d, h/2)
                 +----------------+
                /                /
               /                /
              /                /
             /                /
            +----------------+
(-w/2 - d, -h/2)                  (w/2 - d, -h/2)
```

You have to apply the displacement `d` to the points along the arc, too. The displacement has to be scaled, in relation to the *y* coordinate of the point.
Points near the bottom edge have to be displaced by a larger scale, than points near the center of the left edge:

```
x = circX + cos(angle) * rad
y = circY + sin(angle) * rad

scale = y / (h/2)
x = x - d * scale
```

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76 i tried your solution but still it is not working i have updated the Question with your solution

Comment: i Have updated the code please have a look  , I tried float fscale = 1.0f + y / (float) but it did now work.

Comment: @shomit The height of your rectangle is `yHeight*2`. So it has to be `fscale = y / yHeight;`

Comment: i have tried  fscale = y / yHeight but still it is same as the previous result.

Comment: h/2 was also giving the same result.

Comment: When i look at the picture in your question, then the rounding seems to be correct, but the (half) right edge seems to be wrong. It is not parallel to the left edge.

Comment: Thank you i understand what you mean i think this is the issue.